# How to revert back the dropped table in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have deleted one table accidentally, and now I want it back. so, How can I do that? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you drop any object or you perform anything operation in your database it will get logged in the transaction log file which will be visible by using this function fn_dblog.

Run the below script to display all logs which have been logged under DROPOBJ statement.

```
USE ReadingDBLog
GO
SELECT 
Operation,
[Transaction Id],
[Transaction SID],
[Transaction Name],
 [Begin Time],
   [SPID],
   Description
FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
WHERE [Transaction Name] = 'DROPOBJ'
GO
```

More detail to refer this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3090/how-to-find-user-who-ran-drop-or-delete-statements-on-your-sql-server-objects/